# DataServiceContext : Update Navigation Collection Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm consuming a Odata WebApi.2.1 Service in a Odata v4 client.

When I attempt to update the entity, and I'm getting following error:

*"UpdateRelatedObject method only works when the sourceProperty is not collection"*

I have below code in my application.

```
public class Customer
{
    int CustomerId;
    string CustomerName;
    ICollection<Order> Orders;
}


    public void Save()
    {
        foreach (var item in Customer.Orders)
        {
            Context.UpdateRelatedObject(Customer, "Orders", item);
        }

        Context.UpdateObject(Customer);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here, "Orders" is a navigation property of class Customer. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Rahul

Basically, there are two rules:

1. It is not valid to ***Post*** to any non-collection valued navigation property.
2. It is not valid to ***Put/Patch*** to any collection-valued navigation property.

The public api `UpdateRelatedObject` in OData client is designed to update the non-collection property. In its open source, there are codes as:

```
public void UpdateRelatedObject(object source, string sourceProperty, object target)
{
    ...
    ClientPropertyAnnotation property = parentType.GetProperty(sourceProperty, false);
    if (property.IsKnownType || property.IsEntityCollection)
    {
     throw Error.InvalidOperation(Strings.Context_UpdateRelatedObjectNonCollectionOnly);
    }
    ...
}
```

So, your error message is thrown in the above `throw` statement.

Normally, you can do as follows to make it work:

1. Query the related order, for example:  GET ~/Customers(2)/Orders(1)
2. modify the returned order object
3. update the modified order to call: UpdateObject

Hope it can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sam, BTW I need to bind the orders collection in a WPF Datagrid. Since there is a limitation to get each related order. Is there any way to Modify the Orders collection's entity state to 'Changed' state in client?

Comment: Can you call the following public API:

public void ChangeState(object entity, EntityStates state)

Comment: Sam, How can I call ChangeState() methos. Can you give a sample code?