# How to update a collection of navigation property In Web API 2 with OData v4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, navigation-properties

I'm developing a client server application using Asp.Net WebApi 2.2, Odata V4.
I have generated a Odata v4 proxy class for consume WebApi Odata services in a WPF Application.

I have following models in my solution:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string CustomerName{get; set;}
    public virtual List<Order> Orders{get; set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Part{get; set;}
    public virtual Customer Customer{get; set;}
}
```

There is a one to many relationship exist between Customer and Orders.
Orders is defined as a navigation property in Customer entity;

In the Odata client I have following code to get Customer record.

```
Customer customer = context.Customers.ByKey(1).Expand("Orders").GetValue();
```

It's possible to get, moidify and save tha changes of properties of customer entity.

```
context.UpdateObject(Customer);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But the changes made in navigation property (*Orders*) got lost when saving.
I have debuged the server code (*Controller*) and I can see the changed values (*in `Order` collection*) are sent to the Patch method in server, but not saved in database.

Questions:

1. How can I add new item to Orders collection?
2. How can I modify a property in Orders collection?
3. Should I use `DataServiceCollection<Order>` for track orders
   collection?

Additional Information:
I have created a master detail window in WPF and bonded the order collection to a `Datagdid`.

Comment: Please see my reply in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516358/dataservicecontext-update-navigation-collection-property